# ld: unrecognized -a option `tic-libstdc++' when using -static-libstdc++ in Makefile?

Tags: c++, ld

I am trying to link the "fstream" library to my kernel in C++.
But linker has to have -static-libstdc++ in order for this to work (And G++). But when I go to compile, it says:

```
ld: unrecognized -a option `tic-libstdc++'
```

PS: I typed the whole thing (-static-libstdc++)

Does anybody know why this is happening?
Here is my linker command:

```
ld -z max-page-size=0x1000 -Ttext=0x01000000 -static -Bsymbolic -static-libstdc++ -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) build/GDT/GDTASM.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-static-libstdc++` is a compiler option, not a linker option. You already set the linker to link the object files with static libraries (`-static`). Use `-lstdc++`:

```
ld -z max-page-size=0x1000 -Ttext=0x01000000 -static -Bsymbolic -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) build/GDT/GDTASM.o -lstdc++
```

Libraries must be listed after object files.

It is better if you do not use ld:

```
g++ -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-z -Wl,max-page-size=0x1000 -Wl,-Ttext=0x01000000 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) build/GDT/GDTASM.o
```

Comment: This worked most of the way, just had to add "-Wl, -estart" to g++ and add the function "main" inside of my kernel.cpp. Thanks for your help!